# jQuery [attribute!=value] Selector

Tags: ajax

What would the jQuery selector be that would return just a based on no selection?

```
    parent_fieldset.find('select option:selected').each(function () {
        if( $(this).val() == "" ) {
            $(this).addClass('input-error');
            next_step = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            $(this).removeClass('input-error');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate? Your snippet does now show what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to know how to write a `not` selector in jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I want to how to write a not selector in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery's [Attribute Not Equal Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) or in general [:not() selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to filter elements:

```
$("input[name!='myName']").addClass("myClass");
$("input:not(:checked) + span").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

**UPDATE**

based on the comment, To get non-selected options of a select:

```
 parent_fieldset.find('select option: not(:selected)')
```

Comment: Ok, I mean `<select><option></option></select> .`